# Automation testing of google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, jasmine, karma-runner

Currently, I am working on chrome extension. It is almost finished, but now I have a little problem. How can cover the extension with tests?

For testing separate parts, I have used Jasmin with karma runner. But it works only separately for different files.

For example, it is not possible to use chrome extension API inside of tests, and because of this I cannot send messages to content scripts.

My question is - how can I test the whole interaction between background page - content scripts - web-accessible-resources?

Answer (score 0):

For higher level testing on browsers, if that suits you I use [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) scripts.